# Помогите найти ошибку в проложении для построения графиков D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Приветствую. Пишу приложение на D3 + jQuery.
Оно должно строить различные графики. Информация приходит либо из формы ввода, либо из файла. Столкнулся с проблемой, по какой-то причине приложение соединяет линией первую и последнюю точку графика, таким образом замыкая его. Мне это вовсе не ненужно. Помогите разобраться с проблемой.

---

Мой код

```js
//Добавления строки таблицы

$('.btn').click(function() {
  var ind = $('tr:last').index();
  $('.hide').clone().appendTo('table').addClass('row').removeClass('hide');
  $('tr:last>td:nth-child(2)>input').addClass('x');
  $('tr:last>td:nth-child(3)>input').addClass('y');
  $('tr:last>td:first').text(ind);
  data = [];
});

var rawData = [];
height = 500,
  width = 500,
  margin = 50,
  data = [],
  numb,
  x, y,
  mass = {},
  info;

//функция построения сетки координат

var osi = function() {
  var cur = 0;

  // создание объекта svg
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // длина оси X= ширина контейнера svg - отступ слева и справа
  var xAxisLength = width - 2 * margin;

  // длина оси Y = высота контейнера svg - отступ сверху и снизу
  var yAxisLength = height - 2 * margin;

  for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    if (cur < rawData[i].x) {
      cur = rawData[i].x
    }
    if (cur < rawData[i].y) {
      cur = rawData[i].y
    }
  }
  var sizePlus = cur / 100 * 10;
  numb = cur + sizePlus;

  // функция интерполяции значений на ось Х  
  var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, numb])
    .range([0, xAxisLength]);

  // функция интерполяции значений на ось Y
  var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([numb, 0])
    .range([0, yAxisLength]);

  // масштабирование реальных данных в данные для нашей координатной системы
  for (i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++)
    data.push({
      x: scaleX(rawData[i].x) + margin,
      y: scaleY(rawData[i].y) + margin
    });

  // создаем ось X   
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleX)
    .orient("bottom");
  // создаем ось Y             
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleY)
    .orient("left");

  for (i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++)
    data.push({
      x: scaleX(rawData[i].x) + margin,
      y: scaleY(rawData[i].y) + margin
    });

  // отрисовка оси Х             
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform", // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо
      "translate(" + margin + "," + (height - margin) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // отрисовка оси Y 
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .attr("transform", // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо на margin
      "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")")
    .call(yAxis);

  // создаем набор вертикальных линий для сетки   
  d3.selectAll("g.x-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", -(yAxisLength));

  // рисуем горизонтальные линии координатной сетки
  d3.selectAll("g.y-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", xAxisLength)
    .attr("y2", 0);
}

//функция которая читает значение переменных и записывает из в масив. 

var inputToMass = function() {
  data = [];
  var inpx = $('.x');
  var inpy = $('.y');
  var massx = [];
  var massy = [];
  for (i = 0; i < inpx.length; i++) {
    mass = {};
    x = inpx[i].value;
    x = parseInt(x);
    mass.x = x;
    y = inpy[i].value;
    y = parseInt(y);
    mass.y = y;
    rawData[i] = mass;
  }
  for (i = 0; inpx.length > i; i++) {
    x = inpx[i].value;
    x = parseInt(x);
    massx[i] = x;
    y = inpy[i].value;
    y = parseInt(y);
    massy[i] = y;
  }
}

// общая функция которая при нажатии на кнопку вызывает остальные функции

$('.btn2').click(function() {
  $('svg').remove();
  inputToMass();
  osi();
  chart1();
});

// функция чтения из файла

$('.file').change(function() {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(info) {
    var rezf = info.target.result;
    $('svg').remove();
    data = [];
    rawData = JSON.parse(rezf);
    osi();
    chart1()
    console.log(data);
  }
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
});

//функция построения графика #1

var chart1 = function() {
  // создание объекта svg
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // функция, создающая по массиву точек линии
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  // добавляем путь
  svg.append("g").append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", 2);
}

//функция построения графика #2

var chart2 = function() {

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
  // функция, создающая по массиву точек линии
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
  // функция, создающая область
  var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y0(height - margin)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  var g = svg.append("g");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", area(data))
    .style("fill", "lightblue");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", 2);
}

//функция построения графика #3

var chart3 = function() {
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  var area = d3.svg.area().interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y0(height - margin)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  var g = svg.append("g");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", area(data))
    .style("fill", "lightblue");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", 2);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="table">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hide">
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="number"></td>
        <td><input type="number"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input class="x" type="number"></td>
        <td><input class="y" type="number"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <button class="btn">Add Row</button>

  <button class="btn2">generate</button>

  <input class="file" type="file">

  <pre class="cont"></pre>

  <button class="btnhelp">HELP</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы два раза в массив data добавляли координаты. Исправил пример и подкорректировал параметры svg. Пример рабочий.

```js
//Добавления строки таблицы

$('.btn').click(function() {
  var ind = $('tr:last').index();
  $('.hide').clone().appendTo('table').addClass('row').removeClass('hide');
  $('tr:last>td:nth-child(2)>input').addClass('x');
  $('tr:last>td:nth-child(3)>input').addClass('y');
  $('tr:last>td:first').text(ind);
  data = [];
});

var rawData = [];
var svg1;
height = 500,
  width = 500,
  margin = 50,
  data = [],
  numb=0,
  x=0, y=0,
  mass = {},
  info=0;

//функция построения сетки координат

var osi = function() {
  var cur = 0;

  // создание объекта svg
  svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // длина оси X= ширина контейнера svg - отступ слева и справа
  var xAxisLength = width - 2 * margin;

  // длина оси Y = высота контейнера svg - отступ сверху и снизу
  var yAxisLength = height - 2 * margin;

  for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    if (cur < rawData[i].x) {
      cur = rawData[i].x
    }
    if (cur < rawData[i].y) {
      cur = rawData[i].y
    }
  }
  var sizePlus = cur / 100 * 10;
  numb = cur + sizePlus;

  // функция интерполяции значений на ось Х  
  var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, numb])
    .range([0, xAxisLength]);

  // функция интерполяции значений на ось Y
  var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([numb, 0])
    .range([0, yAxisLength]);

  // масштабирование реальных данных в данные для нашей координатной системы
  for (i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++)
    data.push({
      x: scaleX(rawData[i].x) + margin,
      y: scaleY(rawData[i].y) + margin
    });

  // создаем ось X   
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleX)
    .orient("bottom");
  // создаем ось Y             
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleY)
    .orient("left");

  // отрисовка оси Х             
  svg1.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform", // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо
      "translate(" + margin + "," + (height - margin) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // отрисовка оси Y 
  svg1.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .attr("transform", // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо на margin
      "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")")
    .call(yAxis);

  // создаем набор вертикальных линий для сетки   
  d3.selectAll("g.x-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", -(yAxisLength));

  // рисуем горизонтальные линии координатной сетки
  d3.selectAll("g.y-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", xAxisLength)
    .attr("y2", 0);
}

//функция которая читает значение переменных и записывает из в масив. 

var inputToMass = function() {
  data = [];
  var inpx = $('.x');
  var inpy = $('.y');
  var massx = [];
  var massy = [];
  for (i = 0; i < inpx.length; i++) {
    mass = {};
    x = inpx[i].value;
    x = parseInt(x);
    mass.x = x;
    y = inpy[i].value;
    y = parseInt(y);
    mass.y = y;
    rawData[i] = mass;
  }

  
  for (i = 0; inpx.length > i; i++) {
    x = inpx[i].value;
    x = parseInt(x);
    massx[i] = x;
    y = inpy[i].value;
    y = parseInt(y);
    massy[i] = y;
  }
  

}

// общая функция которая при нажатии на кнопку вызывает остальные функции

$('.btn2').click(function() {
  $('svg').remove();
  inputToMass();
  osi();
  chart1();
});

// функция чтения из файла

$('.file').change(function() {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(info) {
    var rezf = info.target.result;
    $('svg').remove();
    data = [];
    rawData = JSON.parse(rezf);
    osi();
    chart1();
    //console.log(data);
  }
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
});

//функция построения графика #1

var chart1 = function() {
  // создание объекта svg
  //  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  //  console.log (rawData);
  //  console.log (data);
  // функция, создающая по массиву точек линии
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  // добавляем путь
  svg1.append("g").append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill","none");
    
    
}

/*
//функция построения графика #2

var chart2 = function() {

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
  // функция, создающая по массиву точек линии
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
  // функция, создающая область
  var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y0(height - margin)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  var g = svg.append("g");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", area(data))
    .style("fill", "lightblue");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", 2);
}

//функция построения графика #3

var chart3 = function() {
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  var area = d3.svg.area().interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y0(height - margin)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  var g = svg.append("g");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", area(data))
    .style("fill", "lightblue");
  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", 2); 
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hide">
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="number"></td>
        <td><input type="number"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input class="x" type="number"></td>
        <td><input class="y" type="number"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <br><br>

  <button class="btn">Add Row</button>

  <button class="btn2">generate</button>

  <input class="file" type="file">

  <pre class="cont"></pre>

  <button class="btnhelp">HELP</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Благодарю, вы мне крайне сильно помогли. Я использовал пример из учебника по D3. По всей видимости не совсем верный.